# How can I use bash constructs like 'cd' or '&&' or '>' redirection with ddev exec?

Tags: ddev

I'm trying to do some complex things with bash in the container using `ddev exec` and can't seem to get it to work. For example, `ddev exec cd /var/tmp` results in a big error message

```
Failed to execute command [cd /var/tmp]: Failed to run docker-compose [-f /Users/rfay/workspace/d8git/.ddev/docker-compose.yaml exec -T web cd /var/tmp], err='exit status 126', stdout='OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"cd\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

And trying to use "||" and "&&" or shell redirection with ">" doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit 2019-05-14: As of today's ddev release, v1.8.0, the answer below is obsolete, as `ddev exec` and exec hooks are executed in bash context. So `ddev exec "ls | grep php"` now works, `ddev exec "mysql db <somefile.sql"` works, as does an exec hook like `exec: mysql <somefile.sql`

ddev exec (and the "exec" hook in config.yaml) both execute actual comamnds, and not in the context of the shell. "cd" is not a Linux command, but rather a shell built-in. And '&&', '||', and '>' or '>>' are also shell constructs. So we have to do a bit of workaround to make them work.

But we can use bash explicitly to get these things to work:

```
ddev exec bash -c "cd /var/tmp && ls > /tmp/junk.txt"
```

To do the same thing in a post-start hook in config.yaml:

```
   hooks:
     post-start:
       - exec: bash -c "cd /var/tmp && ls > /tmp/junk.txt"
```

Note that environment variables will not persist between exec statements, because they're in different shells, so it's best if you need to keep context to do it in one-liners.

Note also that if you want to redirect stdout/stderr you *can* redirect either within the container (as above) or to the host (redirecting the ddev exec output) like this:

```
ddev exec bash -c "cd /var/tmp && ls" >/tmp/junk.txt
```

It's possible that `ddev exec` might in the future execute commands in the context of bash to make this more transparent.